# Encoding issue while converting .txt file to .xml file

Tags: c#, encoding

I have a .txt file which has more 10000 lines in it and my requirement is to convert each line into an xml file. The encoding of the xml file is iso-8859-1. Everything is getting converted properly except the "NO-BREAK SPACE" which resembles a space but isnt an actual space. It is getting converted to some other symbol(A with a cap). With the xml writer and the stream writer i'm using the encoding iso-8859-1 only.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: It might be useful to know what's the encoding of the `.txt` file.

Comment: And what code does that char have (in your hex-viewer) ?  It should be 0xA0.

Answer (score 0):

If txt file has more characters than iso-8859-1, you can't do this without loosing information.

Either switch to Unicode or require txt file in iso-8859-1.